# How to dynamically update select value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone please help me how to accomplish following?

I have a dropdown field, which have flowers name.The default value is "Select your favorite flower". On tap or click, the dropdown opens and shows the list of options and when user selects a particular value, the field shows the selected flower name.

I need to append Favorite Flower: then the selected value. Can you guys please help me in how to accomplish this?

Please see the image:

[All three states of dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PQ0y.png)

[HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdbwu.png)

```
<select> 
  <list> Select your favorite flower</list> 
  <list>Rose</Rose> <list>Marigold </list>
  <list>Lily</lily> 
</select>
```

Comment: Where are your flowers ? I mean code ?

Comment: share some relevant html code that you have tried so far

Comment: HTML Code

<select>

 <list> Select your favorite flower</list>
 <list>Rose</Rose>
 <list>Marigold </list>
 <list>Lily</lily>

</select>

Comment: @ZohdiR, why are you putting screen shot... just put your real code so that we can help you better

Comment: I am not a developer, hence I have attached the images. Pls see the attached images in the question. many thanks.

Comment: @ZohdiR, `option` or `optgroup` should be child of the `select`

Comment: @ZohdiR se my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a change event, append a span with the text to the selected option:

```
$('select').on('change',function() {
$('option').find('span').remove();//remove previous selected span
var val = $(this).find(':selected').html();//get the text/html of the potion
$(this).find(':selected').html('<span>Favorite Flower: </span>'+val);//change the text with the option
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r5377h21/

or:

```
$('select').on('change',function() {
$('option').find('span').remove();
var selected = $(this).find(':selected'),
    val = selected.html(); 
if(!selected.is('option:first')) {
$(this).find(':selected').html('<span>Favorite Flower: </span>'+val);
}
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r5377h21/1/

Comment: their is a problem. Once the user has selected a particular value from dropdown, the next time he open the dropdown then values are not original i.e. it is no more Rose, Marigold etc rather the first value is: Favorite color:Rose, Margiold, Lily etc. How do we ensure that dropdown value post selection reverts to original values?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

can you please try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/dhavalpankhaniya1989/9ywjntet/3/).

let me know if you need any changes in it

Code :

```
<script>
function test(obj)
{
  $("select option").each(function(){
     $(this).text($(this).text().replace("favorite flower - ",""))
  })
  if($("option:selected",$(obj)).val() != -1){
  $("option:selected",$(obj)).text("favorite flower - "+$("option:selected",$(obj)).text())
  }
}
</script>
<select onchange="test(this)">
  <option value="-1">Select your favorite flower</option>
    <option>Rose</option>
    <option>Marigold</option>
  <option>Lily</option>
</select>
```

Comment: you can do something like this